# map.insert of * argv[]

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I have some problem to understand which parameters would be the right once at the insert function of my `<map>`, maybe you can help me and explaine why?

I wanna open a file, and also save the name of the file which is given by the user over the arguments. To do this I thought it is a good soultion to make a map with a ifsteam, and a string object.

Here is the code:

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        std::map<std::ifstream*, std::string> Dateien;
        auto it_dateien = Dateien.begin();
    
        for(size_t param = 1; param < argc; param++)
        {
            //No valid instance of the constructor
            Dateien.insert(it_dateien,std::pair<std::ifstream*, std::string((*argv[],*argv[]));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What `ifstream` do you want to insert into the map?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do in your code. Please reconsider to edit your question and add further informations of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i want to open a file with std::ios_base::binary mode.

Comment: frankly, the last line does not make any sense. `insert` either takes a pair or key and mapped value, but not both, and you are missing a `>`. Its also not clear why the fstreams are the keys and what the mapped value should be. What exactly do you want to insert in the map?

Comment: While `char *argv[]` is equivalent to `char **argv` as a function parameter, `*argv[]` is not equivalent to `**argv` as an expression.

Comment: If you just want to open a file, then why are you constructing a map? Please talk us through, step by step, what you intend to happen. Start with an example of what the command line looks like, and end with a description of exactly what file(s) is/are opened and why.

Comment: If you want to associate a name with a stream, define your own type that has both a name and a stream.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve you need something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::ifstream> Dateien;

    for (size_t param = 1; param < argc; param++)
    {
        Dateien[argv[param]] = std::ifstream{ argv[param] };
    }
}
```

I assume that you want to save in a map the name of the file you want to read, and to retreive the corresponding ifstream by doing `Datein.at(NameOfFile)`.

For example the usage can be something like this:

```
std::string line;
auto& firstFile = Dateien.at(argv[1]);
if (firstFile.is_open())
{
    while (std::getline(firstFile, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
    firstFile.close();
}
```